# Why won't my Javascript code work? Only half of it works...

Tags: javascript, runtime

My webpage displays the first form correctly, but when I am finished filling out the form, the form should confirm the input and then disappear. The Javascript should also write a new form to the screen, so the next form can also be filled out.

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Week 13 Project - Forms </title>
</head>

<body>




<div id="firstpage">

<form name="personalinfo" onsubmit="nextpage()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
<br>
Gender: <br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"> Male <br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"> Female <br>
<br>
Favorite Color: <br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="white"> White <br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow"> Yellow <br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="orange"> Orange <br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red"> Red <br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green"> Green <br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"> Blue <br> 
<input type="radio" name="color" value="other" onfocus="enablesubfield()"> Other: <input type="text" name="othercolor" disabled = true> <br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Next Page">
</form>

</div>

<div id="secondpage">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var color = "None";
var sex = "Unknown";
var uname = "";
var datacorrect;
var i;

function createpage() {
    var fpage = document.getElementById("firstpage");
    fpage.innerHTML = ""
    var spage = document.getElementById("secondpage");
    spage.innerHTML = "<form name=\"opinion\" onsubmit=\"thankyoumsg\" method=\"post\">" +
    "What brand of cellphone do you have? <br>" +
    "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cphone\" value=\"Samsung\">" +
    "What is the model name? <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"galaxynoteedge\" disabled> Galaxy Note Edge <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"galaxynote\" disabled> Galaxy Note <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"galaxysedge\" disabled> Galaxy S Edge<br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"galaxys\" disabled> Galaxy S <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"galaxygrandprime\" disabled> Galaxy Grand Prime <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"galaxyprevail\" disabled> Galaxy Prevail <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"galaxyalpha\" disabled> Galaxy Alpha <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"galaxyavant\" disabled> Galaxy Avant<br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"galaxystratosphere\" disabled> Galaxy Stratosphere <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"intensity\" disabled> Intensity <br>" +
    "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cphone\" value=\"apple\">" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"iphone\" disabled> Iphone <br>" +
    "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cphone\" value=\"lifesgood\"> LG <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"g\" disabled> G(#) <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"gflex\" disabled> G Flex(#) <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"gvigor\" disabled> G(#) Vigor <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"gvista\" disabled> G Vista <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"transpyre\" disabled> Transpyre <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"optimus\" disabled> Optimus <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"omptimusfuel\" disabled> Optimus Fuel <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"optimusexceed\" disabled> Optimus Exceed <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"omptimuszone\" disabled> Optimus Zone <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"access\" disabled> Access <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"ultimate\" disabled> Ultimate <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"tribute\" disabled> Tribute <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"fluid\" disabled> Fluid <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"f\" disabled> F(#) <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"envoy\" disabled> Envoy <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"realm\" disabled> Realm <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"true\" disabled> True <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"aspire\" disabled> Aspire <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"revere\" disabled> Revere <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"freedom\" disabled> Freedom <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"volt\" disabled> Volt <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"Lucid\" disabled> Lucid <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"Extravert\" disabled> Extravert <br>" +
    "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"model\" value=\"xpression\" disabled> Xpression <br>";
}

function nextpage() {
uname = document.personalinfo.username.value;
if (document.personalinfo.sex[0].checked) {
sex = "male";
} else if (document.personalinfo.sex[1].checked) {
sex = "female";
}

for (i=0; i < document.personalinfo.color.length; i++) {
    if (document.personalinfo.color[i].checked) {
        color = document.personalinfo.color[i].value;
        break;
    }
}

datacorrect = confirm("Your name is " + uname + ", you are a " + sex + ", and your favorite color is " + color + ". Is this Correct?");

if (datacorrect) {
    createpage();
} else {
    alert("Okay, make your changes and then click the \"Next Page\" button again when you are ready.");
}




}

function enablesubfield() {
    document.personalinfo.othercolor.disabled = false;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What the page does instead of the expected results?

Comment: Yeah, the question is a bit vague, could you elaborate more on expected vs found outcode. Also porting it to http://jsfiddle.net/ is always a good way to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish typing my question before submitting it... How do I edit my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really confused about submit page action and js running.
When you click submit it will send request to the server and reload page.( it means your js will never run or you will never see the result of onsubmit() )
so you should split second page to another file and redirect page when user click submit.